# Confusion on usage of か marking alternatives with verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntax, particle-か, coordination

Most textbooks note that using か to mark two noun alternatives, the last one can be omitted. However, what about verbs?

Would a textbook sentence such as

> 今晩の食事はステーキにするか、すしにするかまだ決めていません。

Stay grammatical as

> 今晩の食事はステーキにするか、すしにするまだ決めていません。

In other words, I've been coming across this single か after verb structure and I wonder if it serves the same disjunctive purpose or if it's something else?

Comment: Not grammatically.  Sounds funky, too.  To boot, you'd use the か only if you have one.食事はステーキにするかまだ決みていません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Most textbooks note that using か to mark two noun alternatives, the last one can be omitted.

You are probably talking about something like this:

> ステーキか、すしにします。 / ステーキか、すしを食べます。
>   (I'll have either steak or sushi.)

However, you cannot omit the second か in a sentence like below, even though か marks two noun alternatives:

> ステーキか、すしか(を)、まだ決めていません。(I haven't decided whether I'll have steak or sushi.)
>   *ステーキか、すし(を)まだ決めていません。

Same goes with verbs; you can say

> 今晩の食事は、ステーキにするか、すしにします。
>   (either have steak or have sushi) -- You don't need a 2nd か.
>   今晩の食事はステーキにするか、すしにするかまだ決めていません。
>   (whether I'll have steak or have sushi) -- The 2nd か cannot be omitted.

but not

> *今晩の食事はステーキにするか、すしにするまだ決めていません。

Comment: ”今晩の食事は、ステーキにするか、すしにします。
(either have steak or have sushi) -- The 2nd か can be omitted.”  Where is the second か?  I know exactly what you are talking about but Japanese-learners may not.

Comment: @l'électeur I thought the second か originally was in  「今晩の食事は、『ステーキにするか、すしにするか』のどちらかにします。」 --> rewrite it as ステーキにするか、すしにします then the 2nd か is gone.

Comment: In the sentence 今週中に、メールを出すか電話をかけるかしますから、待っていてください, what's the difference in nuance between this and when you use ~をかけますから~?